# setDrawingCacheEnabled

Tags: java, android

```
finalImgscreen //My View.

finalImage     //My Bitmap

finalImgscreen.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

finalImage = finalImgscreen.getDrawingCache();
```

This works Fine on QVGA screen Emulator/Device,but shows black screen on HVGA screen Emulator/Device.

Can you help me out of it.

Answer (score 0):

before calling `getDrawingCache()`

Call `onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom);`

Try `onLayout(true,0,0,100,100);`